# How to install dbms_defer system package in oracle 11g database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

We have references to dbms_defer package in a pl/sql procedure. This procedure is currently invalid because dbms_defer package does not exists in the database. The DBA tried to provide execute grants but later found out that dbms_defer package does not exists in the database. Can anyone please let me know if there is a way to install dbms_defer and all the dependent packages in the database? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are files that contain `DBMS_DEFER`, all located in (for my 11gXE) `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\`

- catdefer.sql
- catdefrt.sql
- dbmsdefer.sql  >>> contains `CREATE DBMS_DEFER_...` packages
- dbmsgen.sql
- dbmspipe.sql
- execrep.sql

I presume (as I don't know exactly) that the marked `DBMSDEFER.SQL` is what you're looking for.